# MySQL - timestamp column as an signed in

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Seeing some unusual behavior, wanted to get some other feedback.

I have the following:

```
`created_at` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

And I want to group rows into 15 minute chunks, akin to:

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) DIV 900
```

But when I view this number, it's huge and well beyond the upper limit of a signed int column.

What is the proper way to chunk an int column used to store unix timestamps?

Is this enough?

```
created_at DIV 900
```

Comment: `created_at` is already a numeric timestamp, you shouldn't call `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` on it. Just use `created_at DIV 900`.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks that's what I figured. We having a problem migrating from a non-strict MySQL instance to a strict MySQL instance and keep getting invalid datetime errors. I suspect this is the cause.

Comment: @Barmar you mind adding answer so I can accept?

Comment: You already have it in the question, what's the point?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct, you should check leftover of full hour by MOD operator, than divide that value with 900 and take FLOOR value of result. Now you could get 0, 1, 2, 3 representing any value between full hour plus 899 seconds, between full hour plus 1799 seconds, between full hour plus 2699 seconds and between full hour plus 3599 seconds.

```
FLOOR(MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP, 3600) / 900)
```

Or

```
MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP, 3600) DIV 900
```